# Patsy equivalent for the Fixed effects model

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

I am trying to create a Fixed Effects model on Python using the following Python code -

```
t = time 
model = feols(y ~ g1*p + t + geo + indus| geo^t + indus^t , data=data)
```

What would be its patsy equivalent?
How can we create this on PanelOLS?

Comment: There is no patsy equivalent sadly

Comment: do you have a dataset or minimal working example in R with simulated data? I can try to get this working